# Python importing statsmodels no module named 'scipy.linalg'

Tags: python, statsmodels

I've installed scipy and statsmodels, but encounter an error when attempting to import statsmodels:

```
$ pip install scipy
$ pip install statsmodels
$ python
>>> import statsmodels as sm

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/pa354/software/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/statsmodels/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from statsmodels.tools.sm_exceptions import (ConvergenceWarning, CacheWriteWarning,
  File "/home/pa354/software/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/statsmodels/tools/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .tools import add_constant, categorical
  File "/home/pa354/software/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/statsmodels/tools/tools.py", line 8, in <module>
    from scipy.linalg import svdvals
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.linalg'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade to the latest version of scipy with:

```
$ pip install scipy --upgrade
```